# Why is $|x-2|+4 \ge 10$ equal to $-(\infty, -4]\cup[8,\infty)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve a inequality with absolute value variable:

$|x-2|+4 \ge 10$

The solution is provided as $-(\infty, -4]\cup[8,\infty)$

However, I arrived at

$-(\infty, -12]\cup[8,\infty)$

The book says -4 and I cannot see how it's not -12.

$|x-2|+4 \ge -10$

$x+2 \ge -10$

$x \ge -12$

For the other part, $x-2+4 \ge 10$, I'm aligned with the book and arrive at $8>=\infty$

How can I arrive at the text book solution of -4?

Comment: $|x-2|\geq 6$ then $x-2 \geq 6$ or $x-2 \leq -6$

Comment: You mean "Why is *the solution set of* $|x-2|+4\geq 10$ equal to $(-\infty,-4]\cup [8,\infty)$"

Comment: Why did you change $10$ to $-10$?

Comment: It doesn't say $|x-2|+4\geq -10$

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $|x-2|\geq6$. Intuitively, what points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ have distance from the point 2 greater than 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;dr is you are having an issue with absolute value. Let's do it step by step.

$$|x-2|+4 \geq 10
$$
will hold if and only if $|x-2|\geq 6$ holds. Remind that $|a|= a$ wherever $a$ is positive, and $|a|=-a$ wherever $a$ is negative (for $a$=0, it doesn't matter, it's zero either way). In your case, $a= x-2$.

So we actually have two inequations:

- $x-2 \geq 6$, for $x\geq 2$, and
- $-(x-2) \geq 6$, for $x<2$.

The first one yields that $x\geq 8$, so $x\in [8,\infty)$ shall verify the inequality. The second one can be rewritten as $x-2\leq-6$ (why?), so it yields $x\leq-4$. Thus, $x\in (-\infty,-4]$ shall verify the inequality.

We put together the two intervals to say that $x\in (-\infty,-4]\cup [8, \infty)$ is the solution of this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

You're not applying the rules correctly.

From $|x-2|+4 \ge 10$ you should get $|x-2| \ge 6$. From there you get

$$\text{$x-2 \le -6 \quad$ or $\quad x-2 \ge 6$}$$

The rest will follow.

Answer (score 1):

Because $|x-2|+4 \ge 10\iff |x-2|\ge6\iff x-2\ge6$ or  $x-2\le-6$  i.e. $x\ge8$ or $x\le-4$.

Answer (score 1):

$|x-2|+4\geq 10$

$|x-2|\geq 6$

Recall whenever we have $|x|$ we can have two cases,

$|x|=~~~ x\rm{~~ if }~~ x \gt 0$

$~~~~~=-x ~~\rm{ if }~~ x \lt 0$

Hence we can have $x-2 \ge 6$ i.e. $x \ge 8$
else we can also have $-(x-2)\geq 6$ i.e. $x-2 \leq -6$ (we flip the inequality if multiplied by $-1$). This will give us $x \leq -4$.
Therefore valid interval satisfying $x$ is $\boxed{x\in (-\infty,-4]\cup[8,\infty) }$.

[image]